# tf.keras.metrics.SpecificityAtSensitivity num_thresholds interpretation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to get my head around [tf.keras.metrics.SensitivityAtSpecificity](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/SensitivityAtSpecificity). I'm fine with the concept of sensity and specificity in isolation, but I'm unsure how the two are related in this single metric.

More specifically, I'm unsure how to interpret the `num_thresholds` argument. The example in documentation has `num_thresholds=1`. Setting `num_thresholds` greater than 1 with the same input data seems to always return a metric value of 1.0.

```py
def print_metric_value(num_thresholds):
    # other values based on docs example
    m = tf.keras.metrics.SensitivityAtSpecificity(
        0.4, num_thresholds=num_thresholds)
    m.update_state([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.9])
    print('Result with num_thresholds = %d: %.1f' %
          (num_thresholds, m.result().numpy()))

print_metric_value(1)    # 0.5 - same as docs
print_metric_value(2)    # 1.0
print_metric_value(200)  # 1.0
```

Comment: Related: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6507

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `num_thresholds` refers to the number of thresholds. But you might ask: what is a threshold (in this context)? And the answer is that the threshold, which is in the range [0,1], is actually the value which all the predictions greater than that will be considered as positive (i.e. 1) and all the prediction lower than that will be considered as negative (i.e. 0).

For example, consider the prediction vector as `[0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.9]` which are actually confidences scores (e.g. probabilities). Now if we apply the threshold value of `0.1`, we get `[0, 1, 1, 1]`; or if we apply threshold value of `0.6` we get `[0, 0, 0, 1]` (i.e. only the confidence of last prediction is higher than `0.6`).

Now suppose you want to monitor the changes to specificity at a fixed sensitivity. What `SensitivityAtSpecificity` metric does is that, to compute the value of sensitivity, it would first compute the specificity at different thresholds and then chooses the threshold which has the closest specificity to the specificity value you have provided (for example, in your question you have given `0.4` as the specificity value). Then the sensitivity is computed at that threshold and will be returned as the value of this metric. The same thing applies to `SpecificityAtSensitivity` metric, just swap "specificity" and "sensitivity" in this paragraph.

You might also ask: what are the threshold values? The answer is if `num_thresholds=1` then the only threshold is 0.5. If `num_thresholds > 1` then, besides 0 and 1 as thresholds, the interval (0,1) will be split into `num_thresholds - 1` equal sub-intervals and the split points are chosen as additional threshold values. For example:

```
num_threshold  |  thresholds
=============================
1              | [0.5]
2              | [0, 1]
3              | [0, 0.5, 1]
4              | [0, 0.33, 0.66, 1]
5              | [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
...
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Turns out my data leads to ambiguous thresholds - anything in (0, 0.5) gives a specificity of 0.5 (closest possible value to 0.4), but the sensitivity value changes dramatically at 0.3

Comment: One final question: am I right in concluding that `SpecitivityAtSensitivity(anything, num_thresholds=1)` is equivalent to `Specitivity(0.5)`?

Comment: @DomJack Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by `Specificity(0.5)` (I could not find such a metric in TF!). The `SpecitivityAtSensitivity(anything, num_thresholds=1)` would be equivalent to returning the specificity value at threshold 0.5, because that's the only threshold we have considered.

Comment: I'd just assumed it existed, guess not :). Thanks again.

Comment: After a training cycle, during which the net maximized the spec@sens, how can i get the threshold keras used at the very end ? the num_threshold was manualy set at 100.

Comment: @arj I don't think the selected threshold is stored in the metric class, say as an attribute. But I am not %100 sure and you may inspect the [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L1682-L1770) further to confirm this.